# What errors does discord.py hide by default?

Tags: python, logging, discord.py

I've seen mentioned in many posts on Stack Overflow that discord.py "hides errors" by default, if logging is not configured. In the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logging.html#logging-setup), it is mentioned that:

> It is strongly recommended that the logging module is configured, as **no** errors or warnings will be output if it is not set up. [emphasis mine]

However, in discord.py 1.7.3, I observed that errors are outputted to the console. Running the following code snippet:

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    raise ValueError

client.run(TOKEN)
```

properly raises a `ValueError` - the error is not swallowed.

In discord.py 2.0, logging is already set up, as evidenced by the output (with the same code snippet):

```py
[2022-07-15 12:28:40] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
[2022-07-15 12:28:41] [INFO    ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has sent the IDENTIFY payload.
[2022-07-15 12:28:41] [INFO    ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: ...).
[2022-07-15 12:28:43] [ERROR   ] discord.client: Ignoring exception in on_ready
# ^-----------------^ These lines are all from the logging module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TheFu\PycharmProjects\mcve2.0\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 456, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\TheFu\PycharmProjects\mcve2.0\main.py", line 8, in on_ready
    raise ValueError
ValueError
```

So, if logging hasn't been set up in discord.py 1.7.3, why is an error outputted? What errors **do** get swallowed in this version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, in 1.7.3, it completely bypasses logging and prints directly to stderr ([code here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/v1.7.3/discord/client.py#L397)):

```py
async def on_error(self, event_method, *args, **kwargs):
    print('Ignoring exception in {}'.format(event_method), file=sys.stderr)
    traceback.print_exc()
```

The `on_error` is then called like this [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/462ba84809f43349296c44cbe6468f631a00edab/discord/client.py#L341):

```py
    async def _run_event(self, coro, event_name, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            await coro(*args, **kwargs)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            pass
        except Exception:
            try:
                await self.on_error(event_name, *args, **kwargs)
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                pass
```

Regardless of whether logging is set up or not, it does this.

---

I tested it with this stripped down version of a bot. Note that it has the `_run_event` in the error message which should be the same one linked in the code above.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import logging
import sys

LOGGING_ENABLE = True
if LOGGING_ENABLE:
    log = logging.getLogger()
    log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('\033[0;36m%(asctime)s \033[0;32m%(levelname)s\033[0;0m %(message)s', '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S'))
    log.addHandler(handler)

print(f'discord version {discord.__version__}')
intent = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='sudo ', intents=intent)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('logged in')
    print('raising exception!')
    raise ValueError()

print('starting client.run:')
client.run(...)
```

which gives when logging is **not** set up

```
discord version 1.7.3
starting client.run:
logged in
raising exception!
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/greateric/Documents/PYTHON/old-discordbot/bot_cut.py", line 14, in on_ready
    raise ValueError()
ValueError
```

and gives when logging **is** set up

```
discord version 1.7.3
starting client.run:
20220717 14:50:10 INFO logging in using static token
20220717 14:50:11 INFO Shard ID None has sent the IDENTIFY payload.
20220717 14:50:12 INFO Shard ID None has connected to Gateway: <a bunch of irrelevant stuff>.
logged in
raising exception!
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/greateric/Documents/PYTHON/old-discordbot/bot_cut.py", line 23, in on_ready
    raise ValueError()
ValueError
^C20220717 14:50:15 INFO Cleaning up tasks.
20220717 14:50:15 INFO Cleaning up after 1 tasks.
20220717 14:50:15 INFO All tasks finished cancelling.
20220717 14:50:15 INFO Closing the event loop.
```

---

In 2.0, with logging enabled, it does actually "nicely" print the error.

```
discord version 2.0.0a
20220717 14:53:09 WARNING PyNaCl is not installed, voice will NOT be supported
starting client.run:
2022-07-17 14:53:09 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
20220717 14:53:09 INFO logging in using static token
2022-07-17 14:53:09 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has sent the IDENTIFY payload.
20220717 14:53:09 INFO Shard ID None has sent the IDENTIFY payload.
2022-07-17 14:53:09 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: ...).
20220717 14:53:09 INFO Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: ...).
logged in
raising exception!
2022-07-17 14:53:12 ERROR    discord.client Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/greateric/Documents/PYTHON/old-discordbot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 456, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/greateric/Documents/PYTHON/old-discordbot/bot_cut.py", line 23, in on_ready
    raise ValueError()
ValueError
20220717 14:53:12 ERROR Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/greateric/Documents/PYTHON/old-discordbot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 456, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/greateric/Documents/PYTHON/old-discordbot/bot_cut.py", line 23, in on_ready
    raise ValueError()
ValueError
```

(I don't know what's happening here, but I think it's two logging handlers fighting over each other. Screenshot with colors [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4rTe.png))

In fact, when I disable logging, this happens:

```py
discord version 2.0.0a
starting client.run:
2022-07-17 14:56:40 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
2022-07-17 14:56:40 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has sent the IDENTIFY payload.
2022-07-17 14:56:40 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: 85657d0594417664850b2c03c2ca0d77).
logged in
raising exception!
2022-07-17 14:56:42 ERROR    discord.client Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/greateric/Documents/PYTHON/old-discordbot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 456, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/greateric/Documents/PYTHON/old-discordbot/bot_cut.py", line 23, in on_ready
    raise ValueError()
ValueError
```

It seems like discord.py is making its own logging handler now (independent of the one I created last time).

The code *is* different. ([code snippet](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/52f3a3496bea13fefc08b38f9ed01641e565d0eb/discord/client.py#L516), from commit `52f3a3496bea13fefc08b38f9ed01641e565d0eb`)

```py
async def on_error(self, event_method: str, /, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        """|coro|
        The default error handler provided by the client.
        By default this logs to the library logger however it could be
        overridden to have a different implementation.
        Check :func:`~discord.on_error` for more details.
        .. versionchanged:: 2.0
            ``event_method`` parameter is now positional-only
            and instead of writing to ``sys.stderr`` it logs instead.
        """
        _log.exception('Ignoring exception in %s', event_method)
```

The logger is independent of your own set up logger due to [this](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/52f3a3496bea13fefc08b38f9ed01641e565d0eb/discord/client.py#L98):

```py
_log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

It also adds a handler in [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/52f3a3496bea13fefc08b38f9ed01641e565d0eb/discord/__init__.py#L83):

```py
logging.getLogger(__name__).addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

---

Take these two files for example:

`a.py`

```py
import logging
import sys

handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('\033[0;36m%(asctime)s \033[0;32m%(levelname)s\033[0;0m %(message)s', '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S'))
logging.getLogger(__name__).addHandler(handler)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.info('hi from a.py')
print('done executing a.py')
```

`b.py`

```py
import logging
import a
import sys

LOGGING_ENABLE = True
if LOGGING_ENABLE:
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('\033[0;33mreminder that this is the formatter of b.py \033[0;36m%(asctime)s \033[0;32m%(levelname)s\033[0;0m %(message)s', '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S'))
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.info('hi from b.py')

print('just finished running b.py')
```

This is the output if `LOGGING_ENABLE` is enabled. The two loggers are completely independent of each other (they have different formatters).

```
20220717 15:10:49 INFO hi from a.py
done executing a.py
reminder that this is the formatter of b.py 20220717 15:10:49 INFO hi from b.py
just finished running b.py
```

When there is no logger in `b.py`, `a.py`'s logger still works:

```
20220717 15:11:19 INFO hi from a.py
done executing a.py
just finished running b.py
```

Discord.py's 2.0 logger is independent of your code's logger or lack of one. Its own logger will always print the errors regardless of what your own logger setup is.

---

No errors (except for non-`Exception` errors like `KeyboardInterrupt` and the such) should be swallowed in either version. The [`_run_event`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/52f3a3496bea13fefc08b38f9ed01641e565d0eb/discord/client.py#L448) is basically the same in 2.0:

```py
    async def _run_event(
        self,
        coro: Callable[..., Coroutine[Any, Any, Any]],
        event_name: str,
        *args: Any,
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> None:
        try:
            await coro(*args, **kwargs)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            pass
        except Exception:
            try:
                await self.on_error(event_name, *args, **kwargs)
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                pass
```

If there's "no error", it generally means that it was purposely ignored, for example if you overwrite the error handler. It could also be that your terminal was ignoring stderr for some reason, which happened to me once in a different project.

In 1.7.3, the errors will be printed to stderr regardless of any logging configuration, and in 2.0, the errors will be logged using discord's logger.

When it says that nothing will be output on the docs, it means the extra logged information, such as the `logging in using static token` information. The error tracebacks are still printed directly to stderr.